# Extract number from SPFieldNumber object

Tags: c#, sharepoint

It puzzles me how values are retrieved from SPField objects. There are a myriad of methods available for an SPFieldNumber object, however, no one seems to return an integer or anything like that... How do I get the numerical value stored in a SPFieldNumber object?

```
SPFieldNumber mySPFieldNumber = (SPFieldNumber) myListItem["myFieldKey"];
int myNumber= mySPFieldNumber.????
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but shoud due...
int number = myListItem["myFieldKey"] as int;